# How to extend Shopware 6 search so it would search by custom fields, manufacturer name, product id, etc?

Tags: e-commerce, shopware, subscriber

The current Shopware 6 search does not search through all product attributes.

How to change it so it would search by custom fields, properties, ean, etc?

I was trying to create a subscriber to the ProductSuggestResultEvent but got no result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate `Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SearchKeyword\ProductSearchKeywordAnalyzer` in your `src/Resources/config/services.xml`.

```xml
<service id="CustomAnalyzer"
         decorates="Shopware\Core\Content\Product\SearchKeyword\ProductSearchKeywordAnalyzer">
    <argument type="service" id="CustomAnalyzer.inner" />
</service>
```

In your own Analyzer you're able to get the original Response by executing the parent function:

```php
class CustomAnalyzer implements ProductSearchKeywordAnalyzerInterface {
    [...]

    public function analyze(ProductEntity $product, Context $context): AnalyzedKeywordCollection {
        $keywords = $this->originalService->analyze($product, $context);

        [...]
    }
}
```

If you want to add other entities you're able to do so by defining those in your `services.xml`.

Comment: I implemented the  ProductSearchKeywordAnalyzerInterface as you said. In the constructor I have used the same class 

    public function __construct(ProductSearchKeywordAnalyzerInterface $productSearchKeywordAnalyzerInterface)
    {
        $this->originalService = $productSearchKeywordAnalyzerInterface;
    }

Comment: I then tried to add the custom fields. Is this the right direction?
 
    public function analyze(ProductEntity $product, Context $context): AnalyzedKeywordCollection 
    {
        $keywords = $this->originalService->analyze($product, $context);

        if ($product->getCustomFields()) {
            $customFields = $product->getCustomFields();
            foreach ($customFields as $customField){
                $keywords->add(new AnalyzedKeyword($customField, 500));
            }
        }
        return $keywords;
    }
}

Comment: That's the right way. Even tho you should check which type the $customField is. Customfields could also be switches or Associated Id's. AnalyzedKeyword is only expecting strings. You could, but shouldn't for obvious reasons, cast all $customFields to strings or check the type/value behind it.

Comment: If you want to add associated values like `tags` or something like that you'd need to search the product in the productRepository with added Associations. The `ProductEntity` injected by the `analyze` function only has some basic data included.

Comment: I have tried to use the default get methods of product entity, however nothing happens. Here is what I did.

$keywords = $this->originalService->analyze($product, $context);
        if ($product->getWeight()){
            $keywords->add(new AnalyzedKeyword(strval($product->getWeight()), 500));
        }

Comment: I wonder what you are actually trying to achieve by adding the weight to the search index.. but never the less that's actually the correct code for the purpose.
You need to execute `./bin/console dal:refresh:index` every time you change something in the analyze function. It's not computed in realtime while searching for performance reasons.

Comment: For example if a weight of a product is 0.83, I want to type 0.83 in search bar and see that product in the results.

Comment: okay, but that should work with your code after executing `./bin/console dal:refresh:index` and clearing the cache(`./bin/console cache:clear`).

Comment: That worked indeed I was just refreshing the indices through admin page, the execution of the command helped indeed. And the searched worked! Thanks!

Comment: The only problem that I see is that the product entity in the analyzer has all of its fields except of the customFields, the get method always returns NaN. Do you know how to get that in analyzer as well? It is also a NaN in the ProductSuggestResultEvent event.

Comment: I tried it with `$product->getCustomFields()` which worked for me. Try debugging it with `dump($product)` respectively `dump($product->getCustomFields())`. The values should be there, maybe some manipulation you're doing afterwards is malfunctioned.

Comment: When I dump the product entity, I see that my custom fields are stored under - translated->customFields. I tried to get them through other methods but was unsuccessful.

Comment: both the $product->getTranslations() and getCustomFields return null

Comment: As previously mentioned the `$product` entity only includes basic information with small to none associations. If you need data from associations you need to provide the productRepo like so `<argument type="service" id="product.repository" />` and search for the current product with the needed associations. How you're able to do that is found in the docs.

Comment: I got your point, but when I var_dump the product, it has the custom fields with correct values under the translated array. I was wandering if it’s possible to get the value of that protected variable as the getter returns null

Comment: even if I add the repository in the service just as you said, and add the association like this $criteria->addAssociation("product.customFields"); It is still not working, however even without that I think it should work.